# Powershell - Exporting to CSV question

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export just the numerical value for two performance counters to CSV.  I've been able to get something built together but I still need some assistance.

```
    $counter1 = "\\ygex01wal\SMTP Server(_total)\Messages Received Total"
    $counter2 = "\\ygex01wal\SMTP Server(_total)\Messages Sent Total"

    $data1 = Get-Counter $counter1
    $data1cooked = $data1.countersamples | Select-Object cookedvalue
    $data2 = Get-Counter $counter2
    $data2cooked = $data2.countersamples | Select-Object cookedvalue

    $object = New-Object PSObject
    add-member -InputObject $object Noteproperty 'Received' $data1cooked
    add-member -InputObject $object Noteproperty 'Sent' $data2cooked

    $object | Export-Csv c:\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My csv ends up looking like:

```
 
   "Received","Sent"
   "@{CookedValue=2469610}","@{CookedValue=307718}"
```

I would prefer it to look like

```
 
   "Received","Sent"
   "2469610","307718"
```

Any suggestions on how I can get there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the -expandproperty parameter to the select-object cmdlet.

excerpt:

```
$data1 = Get-Counter $counter1
$data1cooked = $data1.countersamples | Select-Object -expandproperty cookedvalue
$data2 = Get-Counter $counter2
$data2cooked = $data2.countersamples | Select-Object -expandproperty cookedvalue
```

Here's a blog post about that parameter:
http://powershellstation.com/2009/11/11/an-overlooked-parameter/